# Reactjs file size: script-file vs npm-version

Tags: reactjs, gulp, minify

I am using reactjs and gulp for the build-process. Currently I use react from npm with browserify. When I want to minify my App in production-mode the react code ends up with about 180kb.

This is the gulp code I use:

```
  gulp.task('production', function () {
    var bundler = browserify('./public/dev/js/main.js').transform(babelify, { presets: ['react'] });

    return bundler.bundle()
        .on('error', map_error)
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(buffer())
        .pipe(rename('bundle-build.min.js'))
        .pipe(envify({'_': 'purge', NODE_ENV: 'production'}))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/dist/js/'));
});
```

However, if I download the minified script files from the react-website and load the script files like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./react.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

it ends up with about 150kb.

Why is the with gulp minified version bigger? How can I bring it to the same size? Also, is there a difference in the development / production of the app between loading the provided script files or using it from npm?

Thanks in advance

Cheers

Comment: Doesn't your gulp task include all your React components in main.js? How big is that file?

Comment: No, for this comparison I took out all my react components. So I only require react + react-dom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browserify uglify via node script or command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413871/browserify-uglify-via-node-script-or-command-line)